# UIAlertview error: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

This question has been asked many times, but I have tried all of the options, and none of them seem to work. In my ios app, whenever I try to make an alert view, this happens:

http://i61.tinypic.com/kalnk2.png

I don't know what to do. When I click ok, I get this error: (This is the entire error)

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BEeGbjJ8

My code is:

```
@implementation AJSettingsViewController
-(NSString*) dataFilePath{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:FILENAME];
}

-(void) saveFile{
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [array addObject:country];
    [array addObject:state];
    [array addObject:town];
    [array addObject:zipcode];
    [array addObject:name];



        [array writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];


    //[array dealloc];
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    zipcodetextfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction)zipcodelookup:(id)sender{
        [zipcodetextfield resignFirstResponder];
    zipcodetextfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

            zipcode = zipcodetextfield.text;
    if(zipcode.length >0){

        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ziptasticapi.com/%@",zipcode];




        url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


        NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
        [connection start];



        NSError *noconnection;
        NSString *htmlpage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]                                                                        encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                         error:&noconnection];
        //NSLog(htmlpage);

        if ([htmlpage rangeOfString:@"error"].location == NSNotFound) {
            htmlpage = [htmlpage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@""];
            htmlpage = [htmlpage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@""];
            htmlpage = [htmlpage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
            htmlpage = [htmlpage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
            htmlpage = [htmlpage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"country" withString:@""];
            htmlpage = [htmlpage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"city" withString:@""];
            htmlpage = [htmlpage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"state" withString:@""];
            NSLog(htmlpage);


        } else {

            zipcodetextfield.text = @"";

            UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                              message:@"We were unable to locate this zipcode. Please try again"
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
            message.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

            [message show];

        }

    }else{
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                          message:@"Please Enter A ZipCode"
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        message.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [message show];

    }
}
-(IBAction)exitkeyboard:(id)sender{
    [zipcodetextfield resignFirstResponder];

}

@end
```

I am at absolute wits end here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You decided to delete the most important part of the error messages. It will list the constraints that can't work simultaneously. That's the bit we need to see. Not the code.

Comment: Whoops, let me add that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
message.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

Do not set this for `UIAlertView` - the alert view and its private manager will decide how its layout works.

Comment: `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` should only be set to false when you create a view in code and wish to position it with explicitly-defined constraints. Looks like there are some other inappropriate assignments in your code (to `self.view` and `zipcodetextfield`).

Comment: I removed them. I had added them because some other posts on this topic said that was the problem. I don't know what is going on

Comment: Is it still crashing without those lines?

Comment: Its not crashing, it is just looking horrible. It still looks like the image above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `delegate:self` instead of `nil` and in your .h file, add `UIAlertViewDelegate` so that it looks like this:

`@interface AJSettingsViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UIAlertController:

```
UIAlertController *myAlertController = [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                      message:@"Message"
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
```

with buttons:

```
UIAlertAction *myCancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel")
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                                   [self someGreatActionWithIndex:0];
                               }];

UIAlertAction *myOkAction = [UIAlertAction
                           actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK")
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                           {
                               NSLog(@"OK action");
                               [self someGreatActionWithIndex:1];
                           }];

[myAlertController addAction:myCancelAction];
[myAlertController addAction:myOkAction];
```

Hope this helps!